# What is MySQL mostly doing?

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to see an overview of what kind of queries are spent the most time on every day on MySQL?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20263/is-there-a-profiler-equivalent-for-mysql#82757

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, mysql can create a slow query log.  You'll need to start `mysqld` with the `--log-slow-queries` flag:

```
mysqld --log-slow-queries=/path/to/your.log
```

Then you can parse the log using `mysqldumpslow`:

```
mysqldumpslow /path/to/your.log
```

More info is here (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/slow-query-log.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can always set up query logging as described here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-log.html

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by 'most time'. There may be thousands if not hundreds of thousands of queries which take very little time each, but consume 90% of CPU/IO bandwidth. Or there may be a few huge outliers. 
There are tools for performance monitoring and analysis, such as the built-in PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA, the enterprise tools from the Oracle/MySQL team, and online services like newrelic which can track performance of an entire application stack.