# View incoming query requests to MySQL server

Tags: mysql, profiler

is there a way we can view the incoming query requests to mysql server. I have a scenario where my asp.net application refuses to execute a query, but the same query executes inside of a mysql query browser. I have installed the mysql dotnet connector (5.0.9) via which I can conncet to the database.

I have referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20263/is-there-a-profiler-equivalent-for-mysql) page, but I guess this will only work within the mysql session. The mysql server is hosted on a centos machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you want [the mysql query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html)

**Edit**: Try this:

1. Edit my.cnf in /etc/mysql/my.cnf
2. /etc/init.d/mysql restart
3. Look in /var/log/mysql

Comment: I tried doing
    /etc/init.d/mysqld restart --log
I was expecting it should give a log but it didn't; I don't know if I am looking in the right place. In /etc/my.cnf file the data directory is reported as /var/lib/mysql. But I can't find the log file there either.

Answer (score 2):

Followed the steps mentioned by Tom Ritter. To be more specific...

While editing /etc/m.cnf (this is where ur mysql config info sits) find a section that says **mysqld**. Just below that type the following:

```
log=/var/log/mysql/generalquerylog.log
```

Do a the rest as mentioned in Tom Ritter's post.

Answer (score 1):

On windows, you can configure a MySQL server instance to log all incoming queries by following the steps below:

- Open your MySQL server configuration file which by default should live at the following path: "**%SystemDrive%\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini**" (note that **5.7** is the version number and could vary based on the version of your instance)
- Locate the following portion of the configuration script:

  ```
  # General and Slow logging.
  log-output=FILE
  general-log=0
  general_log_file="LAPTOP-123456.log"
  slow-query-log=1
  slow_query_log_file="LAPTOP-678901-slow.log"
  long_query_time=10
  ```
- Change the third line of the code snippet from

  ```
  general-log=0
  ```

  to

  ```
  general-log=1
  ```
- Restart your MySQL server

Henceforth, all incoming queries to your MySQL server will be written to the file at the following path: "**%SystemDrive%\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Data\LAPTOP-123456.log**". Note that the file name is the same as the value of **general_log_file** in the configuration script