# MySQL - How to track every query?

Tags: php, mysql, logging, doctrine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to enable MySQL Query Log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479107/how-to-enable-mysql-query-log)

Is there a way to track every SQL query in MySQL?

Im using Doctrine ORM to build entities and fetch them from database, and would like to see what queries is Doctrine producing. So when I refresh a webpage that uses Doctrine ORM to fetch some data from database, where could I see queries executed in database?

Is this possible?

Comment: This won't tell us which HTTP request the queries belonged to.

Answer (score 1):

Enable MySQL's [general query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/query-log.html):

> The general query log is a general record of what [**mysqld**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqld.html) is doing. The server writes information to this log when clients connect or disconnect, and it logs each SQL statement received from clients. The general query log can be very useful when you suspect an error in a client and want to know exactly what the client sent to [**mysqld**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqld.html).

Inside MySQL

```
set global general_log = 1;
set global log_output = 'table' /* so we can query it*/

select * from general_log       /* to select */

truncate general_log            /*if you got to much data*/

set global general_log = 0      /*to turn it off again*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Let this application decide if you want queries logged and log queries on MySQLs side if you want all queries logged.

Doctrine has a builtin logger interface and a demo logger in the package. From http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/configuration.html#sql-logger-optional :

```
<?php
$config->setSQLLogger($logger);
$config->getSQLLogger();
```

> Gets or sets the logger to use for logging all SQL statements executed by Doctrine. The logger class must implement the Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\SQLLogger interface. A simple default implementation that logs to the standard output using echo and var_dump can be found at Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\EchoSQLLogger.`