# Getting the cost of every MySQL query

Tags: mysql

We have a web application backed by MySQL serving hundreds of queries per second.  I'm looking for a way to measure the "cost" of every query in production.  I'm imagining some option where, for every query, MySQL returns the query results *along with* the CPU and I/O cost of executing that query.

The end goal is to aggregate those costs by endpoint (e.g. "/search") and by the logged-in user ID.  That way, when we're having issues with site, we can quickly see if there's a particular action or user ID that is using up a large chunk of our MySQL resources.

**Close but not quite (AFAICT):**

This answer comes close: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12880997/163832

It describes the precision and accuracy problems with `EXPLAIN` and recommends an alternative that measures what actually happened rather than estimating what *will* happen.

The alternative does seem better for my use case, but there are still problems:

- I looked at the available stats and can't find ones that measure CPU or I/O.
- I don't think I can afford to do `FLUSH STATUS` and then `SHOW SESSION STATUS ...` on every query.
- This doesn't work when many queries are running concurrently.

Comment: I think the easiest for you will be to measure the time inside your database class - the method which actually executes the SQL queries. The time is easy to measure and will give you quite accurate picture of the slow queries.

Comment: With your existing workload of hundreds of queries per second,  would you consider an external solution to avoid delaying your business purpose of serving data to your customers?

Comment: @IVOGELOV: We currently do track that, and it is definitely useful.  But I was hoping the DB stats could additional provide I/O information and more accurate CPU measurements.

Comment: This URL will lead you to Performance Schema concepts and data availability since MySQL ~ 5.5.n.  From Percona talent.  Screen shot 35 specifically mentions query data that could be useful for your endeavor.  https://www.slideshare.net/SvetaSmirnova/mysql-performance-schema-in-action-the-complete-tutorial   Have fun, digging deeper.