# Using PDO to CREATE TABLE

Tags: php, pdo

I am very new to php and this forum, so please excuse any errors or misplaced questions. 
In the code i provided, I am just looking to CREATE a Table in the DB "mydb". I tested the connection to the DB(It works). It is just the creating the table i am having issues with.
Any advice or criticisms would be appreciated. Thx

```
<?php
/*
*
* File:         PDOcreateTabletcompany.php
* By:          Jay
* Date:       24-10-13
*
*  This script createsTableintoDB
*
*====================================
*
*/
try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=mydb;host=localhost", "root", "" );
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
$table= "tcompany";
$columns = "ID INT( 11 ) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, Prename VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL, Name VARCHAR( 250 ) NOT NULL,
 StreetA VARCHAR( 150 ) NOT NULL, StreetB VARCHAR( 150 ) NOT NULL, StreetC VARCHAR( 150 ) NOT NULL, 
 County VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL, Postcode VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL, Country VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL " ;


$createTable = $db->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mydb.$table ($columns)");

if ($createTable) 
{
    echo "Table $table - Created!<br /><br />";
}
else { echo "Table $table not successfully created! <br /><br />";
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? You should echo out `$db->errorInfo()` in the else statement to see if there were any sql errors.

Comment: Ask PDO for the error: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info

Comment: I recommend turning on the Query Log. This way you know the exact query that is executing on the server. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479107/how-to-enable-mysql-query-log

Answer (score 52, accepted):

As no rows are affected when creating table $createTable returns 0 see [**manual**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php)

> PDO::exec() returns the number of rows that were modified or deleted
>   by the SQL statement you issued. If no rows were affected,PDO::exec()
>   returns 0.

As you are CREATING a table you will be free from SQL injection if your column names are hard coded( as in the code below). I have left `$table = "tcompany";`as you want to print table created( I would leave it out myself)

I have added [**error-handling**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) which will show any errors in `try` block.

```
$table = "tcompany";
try {
     $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=mydb;host=localhost", "root", "" );
     $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );//Error Handling
     $sql ="CREATE table $table(
     ID INT( 11 ) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
     Prename VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL, 
     Name VARCHAR( 250 ) NOT NULL,
     StreetA VARCHAR( 150 ) NOT NULL, 
     StreetB VARCHAR( 150 ) NOT NULL, 
     StreetC VARCHAR( 150 ) NOT NULL, 
     County VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL,
     Postcode VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL,
     Country VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL);" ;
     $db->exec($sql);
     print("Created $table Table.\n");

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();//Remove or change message in production code
}
```

NOTE in answer to comment use

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I will be able to learn alot from it. I really appreciate the fast reply.

Comment: sir @david how can you create multiple tables using php pdo?

Comment: Just create each table as in example. I would not try to create more than one table at a time.

Comment: This is just what I need! thanks.  I need to check that the table exist or not though so I don't like recreate it if that's even possibble?