# PHP - PDO connection object query not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to create a new table with this code:

```
try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:hostname=localhost",'root','root');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}

//to create database
$db->query("CREATE DATABASE theShop IF NOT EXISTS ;");
$db->query("USE theShop;");

$createTableShops = "CREATE TABLE `advertisor`
                        (
                            `ShopID`        UNSIGNED INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                            `ShopName`      VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,           
                        )type=InnoDB;";

try {
    $db->query($createTableShops);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

at **phpMyAdmin** I browse for the database to make sure if it's actually have been created, I tried the code over and over but it always creates the database **theShop** but with 0(Zero) tables, why the table not created?

note: I've tried some changes:

1. not using backtick
2. changing the type of table
3. changing the key word `type` to `engine`
4. not using neither `type` nor `engine`
5. changing the connection string by adding `dbname=theShop`
6. many things ..!

Comment: the ',' character after `ShopName` field  is not in my code, a fault copying the code nothing more.

Comment: Have you tried this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19577056/using-pdo-to-create-table ?

Comment: yes yes yes!... I've searched alot before asking!

Comment: So it does not create the table but it also doesn't output any error...? Have you checked whether `query()` returns `true`? Are you 200% sure you're looking at the right database?

Comment: Yes I've checked it .. I've tried to do some output if the query is not done correctly .
It also doesn't give any output ... I make an output after all at end of code and the output appears! but the query testing doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (works on my computer : Ubuntu, Apache2, MySQL)

```
<?php
try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:hostname=localhost",'root','pw');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}

//to create database
$db->query("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS  theShop;");
$db->query("USE theShop;");

$createTableShops = "CREATE TABLE `advertisor`
                        (
                            `ShopID`        INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                            `ShopName`      VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL           
                        )ENGINE=InnoDB";

try {
    $db->query($createTableShops);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: on Windows 8 , AppServ -> It Works! thx! ... but what was the fault in my code ?
.you've changed `UNSIGNED INT` to `BIGINT` only

Comment: If you want to use UNSIGNED : go for 
 `'ShopID' INT UNSIGNED` not `'ShopID' UNSIGNED INT` Also, keep in mind you can debug php with console http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.commandline.php

Comment: Yeah I've only changed type to engine and UNSIGNED INT to BIGINT