# mysql stored procedures calls multiple times

Tags: mysql, node.js, stored-procedures, amazon-rds, mysql-5.6

I have created one app using node.js and mysql (AMAZON RDS) as database. recently I have one strange problem with mysql. some of my stored procedures are calling multiple (2-10) times but I have sent single ajax request for the same. I have not seen any error on node. and most of the time this will happen when my app has in its pick time. There is no loop/cursor in this stored procedure, and I am using [pool](https://www.npmjs.org/package/mysql) for mysql connection.
How do I trace, how it's happens? any guess?

Comment: No matter how much you feel it isnt being called more than once, I propose you actually verify that. For instance you can go into the *code* which executes this mysql procedure, add in the same place a log to console or file with the timestamp. Later on, check if there is only one line in log instead of 2-10. After checking we will narrow down the issue.

Comment: @alandarev, that I have tried, but its shows me single time. does mysql has this type of bug or any settings? specially in case of connection pooling? or any error where it tries to attempt mulipul time?

Comment: As far as I know - no. You could also enable noisy mysql logging and try to see what is happening on the mysql server.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479107/how-to-enable-mysql-query-log