# PDO bind array to Where IN

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I want to bind a array of Strings to the `WHERE IN` part of a SQL command, which I want to run afterwards on a SQL Server. The problem is probably that I try to bind an array of Strings and not an array of integers.

```
$totalCount = 
"SELECT referral, COUNT(username) AS cnt FROM accounts
WHERE referral IN ($refIdsPartial) GROUP BY referral";

$ps_totalCounts = $dbh->prepare($totalCount);
$ps_totalCounts->execute();

//loop over total counts
foreach($ps_totalCounts as $row){
    echo "Test<br>";
}
```

**I echoed $refIdsPartial for you, so you have an idea what this is:**

```
54469c27c687b332339627,54469ba0dec3e703865612,54469c77945c7091266617
```

Its just an imploded array of strings/varchars.
I tested the SQL command with my Managementstudio and I can ensure that this SQL command works, as long das I use the quote signs for each String/Varchar. Example:

```
SELECT referral, COUNT(username) AS cnt FROM accounts
WHERE referral IN ('54469c27c687b332339627','54469ba0dec3e703865612') GROUP BY referral
```

**My problem:**

In the code above it never goes into the foreach, so the result of the Query seems to be empty. What is wrong there (Ofcourse I tested only queries which should have results)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use some string manipulation.

You can `count` the number of `?` you'd need by using `str_repeat("?", count(explode(",", $refIdsPartial)))`. This will create your placeholders.

```
$totalCount = 
"SELECT referral, COUNT(username) AS cnt FROM accounts
WHERE referral IN (". str_repeat("?,", count(explode(",", $refIdsPartial))-1) . "?) GROUP BY referral";
```

Now that the placeholders are in place, you can explode the `,` from the string and execute

```
$ps_totalCounts->execute( explode(",", $refIdsPartial) );
```

Comment: but what happens if you use value bind instead of " ? " and when you have more than 1 type of fields at the same time..?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the snippet I use when trying to achieve an IN statement with an array.

This works dynamically, so whether you have an array of 2 or 200 it should execute as expected.

```
$ids = array(1,2,3);
$in  = str_repeat('?,', count($ids) - 1) . '?';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IN ($in)";
$stm = $db->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute($ids);
$data = $stm->fetchAll();
```

Your code will look like so:

```
$refIdsPartial = array('54469c27c687b332339627','54469ba0dec3e703865612','54469c77945c7091266617');
$in  = str_repeat('?,', count($refIdsPartial ) - 1) . '?';
$totalCount = "SELECT referral, COUNT(username) AS cnt FROM accounts WHERE referral IN ($in) GROUP BY referral";
$ps_totalCounts = $dbh->prepare($totalCount);
$ps_totalCounts->execute();

//loop over total counts
foreach($ps_totalCounts as $row)
{
    echo "Test<br>";
}
```

Comment: Will this work for Strings/Varchars as well ?? And I guess $arr should be $ids ?

Comment: @kentor This should work for all data types regardless.

Comment: Hmm I still don't have results from my query. Not sure how I can find out whats the problem. Is there a way to see the whole query which gets executed afterwards, so I can test it on my own ?

Comment: @kentor One way would be to enable to mysql query log, this will show you all executed queries:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479107/how-to-enable-mysql-query-log
Have you tried manually changing the mysql line ie like so:
`"SELECT referral, COUNT(username) AS cnt FROM accounts WHERE referral IN ('54469c27c687b332339627','54469ba0dec3e703865612','54469c77945c7091266617') GROUP BY referral"`

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar problem with quite a big array to bind. Instead of skipping binding and injecting whole array directly to query or making workarounds with dynamically generating multiple unique placeholders to bind each record of array, I went for using `find_in_set` mysql function. [Read more here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set).

In your case it would be:

```
$totalCount = 
"SELECT referral, COUNT(username) AS cnt FROM accounts
WHERE find_in_set(referral,$refIdsPartial) GROUP BY referral";
```