# View what database query is execute from the jBoss console

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jboss

I am using jBoss 5.1.0GA server on which a javaEE application is deployed. I was wondering if there is a way to view the JDBC-SQL queries that are currently executed using console/web-console. I am using mySql 5.5.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using hibernate inside your application then you can turn on the query log as described here: [How to print a query string with parameter values when using Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710476/print-query-string-in-hibernate-with-parameter-values)

If you want to see all SQL's regardless of applicationframework you should enable the mysql query log. This is described here: [How to enable MySQL Query Log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479107/how-to-enable-mysql-query-log)