# Why can't I see MySQL Query in a PhP App?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I wrote a very simple code that connects to a database in my local machine and fetches 5 records as below

```
<?php
$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM myDB.accounts limit 5";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        print_r($row);
    }
    } else {
      echo "0 results"; 
     }
   $conn->close();
?>
```

I would like to be able to capture the MySQL query `SELECT * FROM myDB.accounts limit 5` that I sent to the server in a text file so I can perform some verification on them. I also need to capture Insert/Update/Delete queries.

I run code in Chrome on a Win 8.1 machine featuring XAMPP server. The code works but I am unable to see/capture the query in Fiddler, WireShark, or even Google Developer tools. When I see request in Google developer, I see below:

> Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
>
> Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
>
> Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,fa;q=0.6
>
> Cache-Control:max-age=0
>
> Cookie:ci_session=a%3A4%3A%7Bs%3A10%3A%22session_id%22%3Bs%3A32%3A%22f3bf7b34d76196d3fc0902960e4dbf1a%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22ip_address%22%3Bs%3A9%3A%22127.0.0.1%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22user_agent%22%3Bs%3A109%3A%22Mozilla%2F5.0+%28Windows+NT+6.3%3B+WOW64%29+AppleWebKit%2F537.36+%28KHTML%2C+like+Gecko%29+Chrome%2F44.0.2403.107+Safari%2F537.36%22%3Bs%3A13%3A%22last_activity%22%3Bi%3A1438461576%3B%7Dff60e2b505c1d256c41a21f670827a12401b9667
>
> Host:127.0.0.1
>
> Proxy-Connection:keep-alive
>
> Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
>
> User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.125 Safari/537.36

Also, I would like to know what does CI-Session do down there? I Googled it and found lots of Q&A about user session management with CodeIgniter, but my code has nothing to do with CodeIgniter.

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The SQL query is entirely between your web server and the MySQL server. The browser is not involved in this communication, so it cannot display these queries -- if you want to capture these queries, you will need to do so at another layer. Probably the easiest and most appropriate way of doing so will be to [enable the MySQL general query log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479107/how-to-enable-mysql-query-log), which will cause the contents of every query sent to the MySQL server to be written to a log file.

Comment: Thank you very much. Though you suggestion go enabling log a good one, I am looking for a solution that keeps me away from db engine. Something like wireshark should serve too, but despite many discussion on capability of Wireshark I could not yet make it happen. Any idea?

Answer (score -1):

all your code seems ok,but try changing from `127.0.0.1` to `localhost`.
Check your host in phpmyadmin then click users tab.