# enable mysql query log

Tags: mysql, windows, wampserver

I am using wamp `wampserver2.5-Apache-2.4.9-Mysql-5.6.17-php5.5.12-32b` mysql version is `5.6.17`. It provides mysql and php servers.

**I want to track (see) the queries recently executed (from anywhere i.e a web page, desktop app or any service using mysql on mysqlserver.**

I know **"what to do"** = > i have to enable query logging as told by http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-log.html

But i dont know **"how to do"** though i have seen [How to enable MySQL Query Log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479107/how-to-enable-mysql-query-log)
but i am unable to find `my.cnf` anywhere. What i have is `my.ini` in `wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17`

As i use wamp so I am not familiar with mysql console. I want to know how (where) to set
`general_log_file=/path/to/query.log`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using the WAMPServer menu system edit the `my.ini` file. WAMPServer uses a `my.ini` and not a `my.cnf`

```
(left click wampmanager) wampmanager->MySQL->my.ini
```

This will open the correct my.ini file with notepad.

Check for these parameters and if they dont exists add them under the section heading `[wampmysqld]` or if you are using 64bit WAMPServer the `[wampmysqld64]`

*NOTE: If you are using the 64bit WAMPServer you may have to change `[wampmysqld]` to `[wampmysqld64]` as the 64bit release had a little bug in it and this section header was not set correctly. The filename may also be `c:\wamp64` on 64bit WAMPServer systems.*

```
log-output = FILE
general_log = 1
general_log_file=C:/wamp/logs/general-query.log
```

Save the file and then restart MySQL Server (restart WAMP in your case)

Check in the `C:\wamp\logs` folder for the new `general-query.log` file.

Comment: Correction : `general-log` => `general_log`.
On UwAmp `general_log` and `general_log_file` is enough.
No need of `log-output`

Comment: @Simon Ahh now I understand the correction :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If 64bit version, be sure the log will be created in 
"C:/wamp64/logs/general-query.log"
instead of "C:/wamp/logs/general-query.log".