# Getting Auth User ID in Laravel

Tags: php, session, laravel

If a user logs in Laravel 5.1 we can access user id

```
Auth::user()->id
```

In my previous app (not laravel) when a user logs in I'm registering a session for userid. And I was checking $_SESSION['user_id'] is available or not.

I want to ask that when i call `Auth::user()->id` is it generates and sql query for every request ? If it does it is not good for performance.

Should I register a new session like

```
Session::put('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
```

for performance.

Or Auth:user()->id is best choice ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `Auth::id()` instead. This grabs it from the session. If one doesn't exist in the session, then it will run the query and grab it from the database.

Comment: Does Laravel register session for user id when logging in?

Comment: Yes it does. When you login, it fires this line of code `$this->updateSession($user->getAuthIdentifier());`.

Comment: this is not true, it always does the query

Answer (score 4):

This is not an actual answer, but it intends to show how `Auth::id()` works. Add the following route to your `web.php`:

```
Route::get('/fake', function () {
  \DB::enableQueryLog();
  Auth::id();
  dump(\DB::getQueryLog());
});
```

Now, navigate to `/fake`, which results in the something like:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "select * from `users` where `id` = ? limit 1"
    "bindings" => array:1 [▼
      0 => 284
    ]
    "time" => 15.37
  ]
]
```

I tried this over and over, and it seems that `Auth::id()` always queries the database, as opposed to somehow caching the result in the session (I'm using Laravel 5.6, PHP 7.2.3, and MariaDB 10.2.14).

To confirm, I also enabled [MariaDB logging feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6479183/459391), and I got:

```
180611 12:08:10    77 Connect   user@localhost as anonymous on dbname
           77 Query use `dbname`
           77 Prepare   set names 'utf8mb4' collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
           77 Execute   set names 'utf8mb4' collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
           77 Close stmt    
           77 Prepare   set time_zone="+04:30"
           77 Execute   set time_zone="+04:30"
           77 Close stmt    
           77 Prepare   set session sql_mode='NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
           77 Execute   set session sql_mode='NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
           77 Close stmt    
           77 Prepare   select * from `users` where `id` = ? limit 1
           77 Execute   select * from `users` where `id` = 284 limit 1
           77 Close stmt    
           77 Quit
```