# How do I get the current user Id without hard coding it in?

Tags: laravel

Laravel user id hard coded in

[image]

I currently have the id hard coded in but I want to pull it in from the current logged in user's id.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Auth User ID in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33486838/getting-auth-user-id-in-laravel)

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using laravel authentication you can try this.
`Auth::id();`

Comment: This worked but now I get an error : "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '12' for key 'PRIMARY' (SQL: insert into `files` (`id`, `name`, `size`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (12, Screen Shot 2018-03-10 at 12.01.22.png, 10106, 2018-03-10 12:07:31, 2018-03-10 12:07:31)) "

Comment: are u storing the 12 in th id field

Comment: the error you are getting is because of the field id is a primary key and the table already has a value 12 in the id filed.

try to change the table format

Comment: Yes, so the current user id is 12 but because I have already uploaded something for user id 12 I don't think it will let me upload multiple times for one user?

Comment: files table with the following fields
1 id primary key
2 user_id (store user ids here)
3 name
4 updated_at
5 created_at

Comment: so should I remove the id field as a primary key?

Comment: change the table as i mentioned above

Comment: that will give you unique record id for files and it will allow you to store multiple users files

Comment: sorry but can u see what I'm doing wrong here? I tried to create a new table but it will not generate random ids and gave me the same error again.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `files` (
  `id` int(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `users_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `size` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (users_id) REFERENCES users (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

Comment: Give auto increment to the id and not user_id

Comment: Happy it helped you do up vote comments and mark the answer