# Laravel query returns question mark instead of variable value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

When I click on a button, an AJAX-call is being made to my self written API. When the button is clicked, the Javascript file retrieves two `data`-attributes from the clicked object and sends it along with the URL. The two variables are used in the where clause of the yet to be executed SQL-statement.

When the call is being made, the PHP-script that handles the API requests receives the two variables via `Input::get('data-attribute-one'))` and `Input::get('data-attribute-two'))`. When I output these two attributes, the correct values are displaying.

However, when I put the variables into the where-clause of my query, like so:

```
$fans = Sensor::where('fan_number', '=', $dataAttributeOne)->where('created_at', '>=', $this->now->subHours(6))->get();
```

no results are returned. So I replaced `->get()` with `->toSql()` to check the query and it presented me with this strange line of code:

```
Object {fans: "select * from "myawesomedatabasetable" where "fan_number" = ? and "created_at" >= ?"}
```

`$dataAttributeOne` is the retrieved `data-atribute` and `$this->now->subHours(6)` is the current time minus 6 hours. When I output this, it is in the same format as the `created_at` value in the database and when I hardcode it into an SQL-statement in Phpmyadmin, the query executes like a charm. So no problems there.

So my question is: why are the variables turning into question marks when the query executes and how do I solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Simple answer to your question `Why are the variables turning into question marks when the query executes` they are placeholders as part of [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) it is **not** executed as that, as Alexey has answered is your solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's just how `toSql()` works. This method is used for debugging.

https://scotch.io/tutorials/debugging-queries-in-laravel

Comment: I feel very stupid now.. But I read through the link, installed the Debugbar and figured out what part of the prepared statement went wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Another way to debug sql queries is to turn on mysql debugging so that it logs all queries that have run. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479107/how-to-enable-mysql-query-log