# MySQL Server 5.7.10+: show executed sql from web application

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

When I tried to build my web application, I was stucked for almost a week only because I didnot know to configure url with unicode information. Even if I publish the executed sql by hibernate, when the sql arrives at mysql server, it is actually encoded/decoded to different thing because of the usage of chinese character.

So I wonder is it possible to publish the arrived sql at mysql server side in order to make sure about what is going on at every level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to publish the arrived sql at the mysql server side you should enable query logging

this link is showing how to do that

[How to enable MySQL Query Log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479107/how-to-enable-mysql-query-log)

and official documentation

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-log.html