# How to create a MySQL log using Java

Tags: java, mysql

I am currently using `MySQL` Workbench which already contains a logging mechanism. The problem is, is that the log only logs queries executed within the Workbench.
 Any connections made by `JDBC` isn't actually logged. How do I create a log that incorporates the Java queries into SQL?

I am using `Workbench 6.3`, `SQL version 5.6.31`

Comment: Where do you want the log to be stored?

Comment: Pushed to a table possibly within the db? @Andreas

Comment: log4j - Logging in Database / Files might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need the server side logging. If that's correct, see [How to enable MySQL Query Log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479107/how-to-enable-mysql-query-log).

This, of course, logs all the SQL queries received by the MySQL server (all connections), which means you should use it judiciously.

Comment: That is for SQL version 5.2.9 and earlier.