# Recreate MySQL database from log

Tags: mysql, database, logging, database-backups

Im researching the best way of logging queries in MySQL database. The log should be used for two things:

1. Documentation of system activity
2. Used to recreate the database (in case the database is hacked or otherwise corrupted)

It's possible to log all queries in a MySQL database [(like this example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479107/how-to-enable-mysql-query-log?rq=1)

**Question:** It is possible to recreate a database on the basis of the log file, or should I use a different approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can use replication logs for this - they store the complete set of operations. You should be able to create a new database from original sources and apply all changes upon it.

You can do complete dumps (i.e. once a week) and archive the replication logs on daily basis.