# Zend_Db_Table_Abstract: save - sql injection

Tags: sql, zend-framework, sql-injection

When using the `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract Save` function, to update a database, do I need to worry about SQL injection (quote my parameters) or is it done automatically?

How can I see how the query looks?

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to worry about SQL injection when using `save()`.

Behind the scenes, Zend Framework uses `Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract::insert()` and `Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract::update()`, which use bind parameters. All values will be escaped by the framework to prevent SQL injection.

The only risk of SQL injection is when using `Zend_Db_Expr` to create custom / advanced queries, but this cannot happen when using `save()`.

You may want to have a look on [Zend_Db_Profiler](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.profiler.html) to list all queries generated by the framework.

Alternatively, you can also enable your database query logs. See [How to enable MySQL Query Log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479107/how-to-enable-mysql-query-log) for MySQL, or [How to log PostgreSQL queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722221/how-to-log-postgresql-queries) for Postgres.