# Logging SQL excecuted queries in promise-mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, promise

As defined in [mysql](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql)

```
var post  = {id: 1, title: 'Hello MySQL'};
var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO posts SET ?', post, function(err, result) {
  // Neat!
});
console.log(query.sql); // INSERT INTO posts SET `id` = 1, `title` = 'Hello MySQL'
```

We can see the excecuted queries in log
Please suggest how to log exceuted queries in promise-mysql

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable MySQL Query Log?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479107/how-to-enable-mysql-query-log)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was related to GITHUB [issue](https://github.com/lukeb-uk/node-promise-mysql/issues/39)

**From Github:**

> I'm not sure if this is helpful but you can set debug: ['ComQueryPacket', 'RowDataPacket'] when you create the connection to debug all queries.

Hope this helps.