# Php - odbc Select Where X IN (Select...)

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

I have the following code

```
    $stmt = odbc_prepare($conn, 'SELECT tpedidos.*, users.nome FROM tpedidos, users WHERE CODCLI IN (SELECT idCliente FROM ligacoes WHERE idGest =?) AND tpedidos.estado =? AND users.id=tpedidos.CODCLI');
    $success = odbc_execute($stmt, array($gestor, $estado));
```

My problem is that the $gestor is not being well read in the query and if i put a value instead of the '?' it works.

What can i do?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT 1:

Warning: odbc_execute(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Syntax error or access violation, SQL state 37000 in SQLDescribeParameter in C:****\file.php on line 720

Comment: `not being well read` -- what does that mean?

Comment: The function doesnt seem to be able to figure out where $gestor should go

Comment: It puts the parameters into the query in the order the question marks are and the order in the array -- its one for one.

Comment: i know but i guess because the first one is inside () it doesnt get replace.

Comment: if i put WHERE idGest =18 it works

Comment: Have you tried changing `=?` to `= ?` (note the space)? It may not recognize it correctly because of that.

Comment: the AND tpedidos.estado =? is also like that but i will try

Comment: Tried it, no use :(

Comment: Are you getting an error? How do you know it can't figure out where it goes?

Comment: What is the output or exception/error message? Please post fuller PHP code so we can see how *idGest* is assigned.

Comment: idGest is a field in the DB and i get the following code on the page *added to post*

Comment: try with this: `(int)$gestor`

Comment: @Hatef , didn't work. gave the same error

Comment: You could also check the sql log to see what is the executed query. My guess is, it is changing the datatype.

Comment: Where would i find the sql logs?

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479107/how-to-enable-mysql-query-log)

Comment: look i'm doing an infernal intership and i dont have direct access to the logs.

Comment: Is there any other way in sql to query what im looking for, like a substitute for the WHERE CODCLI IN(), because if so i'll just use that

Answer (score 0):

To reply your last comment regarding an alternative query, you could try with [PDO prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/it/pdostatement.execute.php):

```
$sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT tpedidos.*, users.nome 
                          FROM tpedidos, users 
                          WHERE CODCLI IN 
                            (SELECT idCliente FROM ligacoes WHERE idGest = :idGest) 
                          AND tpedidos.estado = :estado 
                          AND users.id = tpedidos.CODCLI");
$sth->bindParam(':idGest', $gestor, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(':estado', $estado, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();
```

P.S: I assumed `$estado` is a string. If it is an integer replace `PDO::PARAM_STR` with `PDO::PARAM_INT`.