# Laravel 5.4, mysql 5.6.35 empty result when using STR_TO_DATE in where clause

Tags: mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin, str-to-date

I get **empty result** in eloquent query builder, whereas copying the sql (from ->toSql( ) function) and run it in phpadmin **works perfectly**.
This is my query:

```
$reportData=DB::table('my_table')
->select('my_table.*')
->whereRaw("STR_TO_DATE(my_table.date, '%m.%Y') >= STR_TO_DATE('01.2017', '%m.%Y')")
```

The sql equivalent returned by toSql is:

```
select *
from my_table
where STR_TO_DATE(my_table.date, '%m.%Y') >= STR_TO_DATE('01.2017', '%m.%Y')
```

Note: I used another mysql function like UPPER, DATE_FORMAT in whereRaw, and that has no issue; but with STR_TO_DATE it has.

I checked in official site, STR_TO_DATE should work with MySQL 5.7, MySQL 5.6, MySQL 5.5, MySQL 5.1, MySQL 5.0, MySQL 4.1, MySQL 4.0, MySQL 3.23.

Please help :)

--Update--
I rechecked mysql_log and here I had:
 - the first log (id=1) is created when running query through laravel
 - the second log (id=2) is from phpmyadmin

[image]

Comment: I removed the where clause, added a raw select with ```select('my_table.*', DB::raw("STR_TO_DATE(my_table.date, '%m.%Y') as foo")), no problem

Comment: Different time zone settings influencing the date conversion maybe? Can you check whether `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE  'time_zone'` gives a different result when executed from Laravel, and directly in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Can you [enable the MySQL query log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479107/how-to-enable-mysql-query-log) to see if there is a difference between the queries once they actually reach the server?

Comment: @CBroe : both laravel and phpmyadmin return "SYSTEM" as TIME_ZONE.
I think, it's not in time_zone, I even changed the condition with ```STR_TO_DATE(my_table.date, '%m.%Y') >= '0'```, I have the same issue

Comment: @MosheKatz : I updated my question with generated logs from Laravel & phpmyadmin. It seems both queries arrive to mysql.