# Is there a way to monitor/track which php/js script uses which database table is used?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, mysqli, monitor

I'm trying to find a way which php/js script is accessing certain database table
I researched a lot but can't find any solution.

what I want to do is something like list all scripts(especially php) that access/uses specific database table

ex. MySQL TableA (target table)

list all scripts that access TableA

- scriptA.php
- scriptB.php
- scriptC.php

etc.

how can I do this in real time? if not possible output the list in a log file or some file that I can list?

if there is no way how would you suggest to track the scripts that accesses TableA?

Comment: yes, by editing the scripts in question, im guessing you dont want that

Comment: The simplest way would be to search through your source code for references to `TableA`. You could turn on the [mysql general log](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6479183/2624391) but that will only tell you the queries being executed, not the script sending the query.

Comment: @Tim then one might create several different users and the answer would be immediate.

Comment: How about maintaining a separate table? Something like : when scriptA access table1, you can put a recode on that separate tabale. Then you can fetch em in real time by using webSockets or ajax.