# DB Monitoring to get the transaction details

Tags: mysql

I need to trace the MYSQL Database. Is there any way to find all the log details that happened in the database through a query or file. I want to the view the transaction history any time I wish. Please help me.

Thanks
Divya

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your MySQL configuration file by adding the following to the `mysqld` section of the config file:

```
[mysqld]
...
general_log = on
general_log_file = /var/log/mysql.log
```

This will log all transactions to `/var/log/mysql.log` after you restarted the daemon.

EDIT: this question is probably a duplicate of [How to enable MySQL Query Log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479107/how-to-enable-mysql-query-log)