# How to wait for mysql docker-entrypoint-initdb before starting a service

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a dockerized app that uses mysql, express & react.

I need to first initialize mysql with a `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` before starting the express app. However, when mysql server starts it doesn't execute the starting .sql script right away and `my_database_name` starts initially empty.

In that timegap,  my express app starts and tries to query en empty database. Later the initialization script works as intended and fills `my_database_name` which is already too late by then since my express app has already started.

I've tried `depends_on/condition` as shown below but `Version 3 no longer supports the condition form of depends_on` as stated in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/).

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  api-server:
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    image: myapp_server
    env_file: ./server/.env
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    depends_on:
      mysqldb:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    networks:
      - mysern-app
    container_name: my_express_app

  mysqldb:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: my_database_name
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/data/db
      - ./db/backup/:/mysql/backup
      - ./db/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    healthcheck:
      test: 'not sure what to write in here as well'
      interval: 1s
      retries: 120
    networks:
      - mysern-app
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    container_name: my_mysql_app
networks:
  mysern-app:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  mysql-data:
    driver: local
```

I ultimately want to do this sequence:

> Start mysqldb > fill the table from the script > start the express app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things you can do:

1. Add `restart: always` to your `api-server`. If it crushes because MySQL is not yet available - it will restart until MySQL will be available. I'm assuming that your `api-server` will crush if MySQL is not available.
2. In case it won't crush, implement [health-check](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#healthcheck) for your service, so it won't be available if Mysql isn't available.

docker-compose is your orchestrator and it can help you and take care of failures. In real-world, your MySQL might be not available for a second too, and you must know how to handle that.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```yaml
version: "3.7"
services:
  acme-db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: mysqld --sql_mode="" --max_connections=1100 --general-log=1 --general-log-file=/tmp/mysql-general-log.log
    container_name: eventhos-db
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./database:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: changeme
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: changeme
      MYSQL_USER: "usr_acme"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "acme"
      TZ: America/Lima
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 512M
    healthcheck:
      test: 'cat /tmp/mysql-general-log.log | grep "root@localhost on  using Socket"'
      interval: 10s
      retries: 120
```

#### Explanation

**There is not a native way to ask the mysql if dump has been fully imported.**

Researching I found an internal mysql log file called [mysql general_log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479107/how-to-enable-mysql-query-log) and reviewing its [content](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jrichardsz/6d4894ffc369fdf3cbc267ae878be235/raw/62c877e21c0ecc5fa3fd65bfd47ba3c0104f3b67/mysql%2520log%2520sample%2520--general-log-file%2520.log) in dockerized mysql I detected a pattern:

> If everything is ok, at the end this line appear: "root@localhost on  using Socket" just once

[image]

So if we enabled this log using **command:** in docker-compose:

```bash
command: mysqld --sql_mode="" --max_connections=1100 --general-log=1 --general-log-file=/tmp/mysql-general-log.log
```

The health check is just a search of these line

```bash
cat /tmp/mysql-general-log.log | grep "root@localhost on  using Socket"
```

Note: Health check interval less than 10 seconds, don't work!

Comment: Your welcome. Don't forget to share your knowledge too!