# MySql: Get a more precise time measurement than a hundredth of a second

Tags: mysql, sql, benchmarking

When I run a SQL in MySql or I use the `BENCHMARK` command, I get a result like the following:

```
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

0.00 sec isn't very meaningful for some queries, and sometimes more precision is needed to figure out how long a query took in an even smaller unit of time. How do you do this in MySql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into `Profilers`, such as http://www.jetprofiler.com/ and others...

Also, this question has some suggestions: [Is there a Profiler equivalent for MySql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20263/is-there-a-profiler-equivalent-for-mysql)

Comment: Cool, thanks for the reply. Is there anything native to MySQL that will let me get better precision though?

Comment: I don't use MySQL, but you could try it manually using CURTIME()?  If you `SELECT CURTIME() + 0` (the +0 is necessary), do you still just get the time in seconds, or does the micro-seconds part (after the decimal point) actually get filled in?