# MySQL: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Duplicate entry '242-243' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: java, mysql

I have a problem with MySQL, at 4.00 PM my webApp i think cannot reach MySQL because of this errors:

```
    com.webratio.rtx.RTXException: Unable to perform process transition 'startProcess[startActivityTypeOid:2][parameters:gruppoOid=1, idCliente=2613, scontoOcc={}, barcode=10AA1107]'
    at com.webratio.units.bpm.core.ProcessController.handleProcessTransition(ProcessController.java:137)
    at com.webratio.units.bpm.services.ProcessUnitService.createUnitBean(ProcessUnitService.java:151)
    at com.webratio.units.bpm.services.AbstractBPUnitService.getUnitBean(AbstractBPUnitService.java:144)
    at com.webratio.units.bpm.services.AbstractBPUnitService.execute(AbstractBPUnitService.java:107)
    at com.webratio.struts.actions.OperationAction.executeOperation(OperationAction.java:393)
    at com.webratio.struts.actions.OperationAction.doExecute(OperationAction.java:249)
    at com.webratio.struts.actions.OperationAction.execute(OperationAction.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.ExecuteAction.execute(ExecuteAction.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractExecuteAction.execute(AbstractExecuteAction.java:67)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:190)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:304)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:190)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    at com.webratio.struts.servlets.WRActionServlet.process(WRActionServlet.java:155)
    at com.webratio.struts.servlets.WRActionServlet.doPost(WRActionServlet.java:99)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:465)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:390)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:317)
    at com.webratio.struts.chain.commands.PerformForward2.handleAsForward(PerformForward2.java:101)
    at com.webratio.struts.chain.commands.PerformForward2.perform(PerformForward2.java:83)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractPerformForward.execute(AbstractPerformForward.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:190)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:304)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:190)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    at com.webratio.struts.servlets.WRActionServlet.process(WRActionServlet.java:155)
    at com.webratio.struts.servlets.WRActionServlet.doPost(WRActionServlet.java:99)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.webratio.struts.filters.StaticResourceFilter.doFilter(StaticResourceFilter.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2489)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)



Caused by: com.webratio.rtx.RTXException: Unable to start process (startEventOid:2)
    at com.webratio.units.bpm.core.ProcessController$StartProcessCommand.computeOperations(ProcessController.java:557)
    at com.webratio.units.bpm.core.ProcessCommand.execute(ProcessCommand.java:184)
    at com.webratio.units.bpm.core.ProcessController.handleProcessTransition(ProcessController.java:107)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at com.webratio.units.bpm.core.$Proxy3.flush(Unknown Source)
    at com.webratio.units.bpm.core.handlers.ProcessHandler.connectActivityInstances(ProcessHandler.java:1007)
    at com.webratio.units.bpm.core.handlers.ProcessHandler.normalFlow(ProcessHandler.java:256)
    at com.webratio.units.bpm.core.handlers.ProcessHandler.normalFlow(ProcessHandler.java:122)
    at com.webratio.units.bpm.core.handlers.ProcessHandler.startProcess(ProcessHandler.java:109)
    at com.webratio.units.bpm.core.ProcessController$StartProcessCommand.computeOperations(ProcessController.java:550)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor234.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.webratio.units.bpm.core.TXSession$SessionInvocationHandler.invoke(TXSession.java:206)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:262)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1206)
    ... 76 more
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Duplicate entry '242-243' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:2020)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1451)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:297)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:297)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:297)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
    ... 81 more
```

I have no idea what it is because it is never happened to me. 
I am stuck at this, so I thank you in advance for some advices.

Comment: Title does not seem to be connected with the inner error. What SQL statement are you executing?

Comment: I think 'insert INTO', my BPM does it automatically!

Answer (score 1):

Just like the error states:

```
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Duplicate entry '242-243' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

You're trying to insert a value with the same primary key as an existing one ('242-243'). Primary keys are unique, there cannot be any repetitions.

Comment: Thanks for replying,but I want to identify wich table is invoked!

Comment: We don't have access to your code. You need to check which line is throwing it and using a debugger or prints, check the command being executed.

Comment: Oh ok, i tell you more: it happens only at 4 PM, at the moment when i debug seems clear and correct. So it's not a MySQL fault?

Comment: The fault lies with the command being used to insert data into MySQL

Answer (score 1):

`BlueMoon93`'s answer is correct. However, a way to find out what table is affected by this is to use a profiler. This topic is covered by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20263/is-there-a-profiler-equivalent-for-mysql) and answers.

Generally speacking, profiler can be used both for performance checking and see what queries, procedures etc. are running. You need it for the second option, so [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/82757/2780791) might be a good starting point.