# configuration of mysql for improve performance

Tags: mysql, wordpress, iis, windows-server-2012, iis-10

i have mysql on server
all query slow
if  change innodb_buffer_pool_size from  16M to other  number
will down  server  with high traffic
because all query is  very slow
or any other recommendation to improve
thanks for any help

Comment: Learn to help yourself by profiling the performance metrics, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20263/is-there-a-profiler-equivalent-for-mysql Without connecting to your database instance, nobody here can give you more assistance.

Comment: @oracl         Additional information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions. Be very WARY of anyone requesting access to your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`innodb_buffer_pool_size` should be about 70% of available RAM.  16M is too small.